# How to prevent credential dialog of "HTTP Request" action?

Tags: install4j

I am using the *HTTP Request* dialog to check the connection to our server. If the user input for the credentials are incorrect a dialog is shown to set the credentials correctly. Instead of this dialog I want the wizard to go back to the parent screen which contains the customized input fields. So I want to prevent install4j from showing the integrated credentials dialog. Is this possible or do I have to create a customized action to check the http connection?

Answer (score 0):

As of install4j 6.0, there is no way to insert logic into this verification. I've added this as a feature request to our issue tracker.